# Ubuntu 16.04.2 - Chrome hardware acceleration disabled

Tags: drivers, graphics, google-chrome

From chrome://gpu/ it says "Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable" Chrome is a bit laggy like this... How can i enable hardware acceleration ? i have r9 380x graphics card.

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Amethyst XT [Radeon R9 M295X Mac Edition / R9 380X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: f1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Chrome output

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
CheckerImaging: Disabled
Flash: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Compositing: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Rasterization: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Encode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL: Hardware accelerated but at reduced performance
WebGL2: Unavailable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not about Ubuntu.

You can enable hardware acceleration by going to `chrome://flags` and choosing "Override software rendering list".

But you may get some glitches.

Comment: Oh im going to try that. But my question is, why chrome doesnt have it enabled by default?

Comment: Google maintains a list of hardware that they consider glitchy and disable hardware rendering on this hardware.

Comment: Ok i get it now. I enabled it on chrome and its ultra smooth now...i suppose the only problem can be some glitches right? i mean u cant do any damage to the graphics card right?

Comment: No, it is not dangerous.

Comment: This does not enable hardware decode actually, Just check CPU usage. It is available in chromium 67 so it might come soon

Comment: This likely won’t damage the gpu but it is more insecure. Hardware acceleration on common gpu drivers is heavily tested for vulnerabilities. The reason why it is not enabled by default is because Google can’t guarantee the same level of security with your drivers like it does for more common ones.